# dracut: Switching root

Tags: centos, centos6, grub, grub2

After my hosting company did some changes (no technical description for them) I got the following boot error for my CentOS:

[image]

What I must do to get my servers up! I tried to ask for support at the hosting company but...

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem when Update the system and the fix it by removing shortcut with name "update" or something like this, in the root folder.
But It also can happen with a damaged disk.

"Chances are it's wanting you to manually check the disk with fsck to fix it because it can't do it on its own. Probably wants you to choose yes or no for fixing a couple of things. I'd expect just some file system inconsistencies other than a physical problem with the disk, although there is always a possibility for this"

source http://mandrivausers.org/index.php?/topic/109563-dracut-error-on-boot-solved/